# how to calculate the number of days in leap year

Tags: python

Write a program that prompts the user to input a month and a year and then output a message to 
state how many days are in the given month (note: you will need to consider leap years if the user 
enters February for the month)

### i used in the first int and input to enter a month and year

> > if (year/400 == 0) and (year/100 != 0) or (year/4 == 0):

```
print( "this year is a leap year: ")

if ( month == "December" or  month == "January" or month == "March" or  month == "May" or month  == "July" or  month == "August" or month == "October" ):
    print ("days are: 31")

elif ( month == "April" or month == "June" or month == "September" or  month == "November"):
    print ("days are: 30")

elif ( month == "February" ):
    print ("days are: 29")
```

> > else:

```
print( "this year is not a leap year: ")

if ( month == "December" or  month == "January" or month == "March" or  month == "May" or month == "July" or  month == "August" or month == "October" ):
    print ("days are: 31")

elif ( month == "April" or month == "June" or month == "September" or  month == "November"):
    print ("days are: 30")

elif ( month == "February" ):
    print ("days are: 28")
```

the code doesn't work in the correct, it only work with else , so if somebody has an idea about the error 
I think the error in first condition ( if year/400 == 0 ).......

Comment: You probably want the modulo operator `%` instead of the division operator. `year/400` is likely to be 5, not zero for most dates you might work with.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [**isleap()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap) function from the built-in module calendar.

```
import calendar
print (calendar.isleap(1900))
```

Prints `False` because 1900 is not a leap year.

Comment: I'm assuming your not a native python coder, print does not return, and isleap is not a built-in something is only built-in if it is automatically in global scope, not imported.

Comment: 1. You're assuming wrong. 2. I meant return as in outputs. 3. Built-in is technically the correct word. It means it ships with the Python package.

Answer (score 0):

use a helper function like this:

```
def is_leap(n): 
    if n % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if n % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if n % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if is_leap(year):
    #your code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

def days_in_month(year, month):
    list_31 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
    list_30 = [4,6,9,11]
    if month in list_31 :
        return 31
    elif month in list_30 :
        return 30
    elif is_year_leap(year) and month == 2:
        return 29
    # elif is_year_leap(year) != True and month == 2:
    else:
        return 28


x = int(input('Enter any year: '))
y  = int(input('Enter a month: '))


l_p = is_year_leap(x)
month_in_lp = days_in_month(x,y)

print(l_p, month_in_lp)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just see if the year is divisible by 4. If so, it's a leap year.

```
if not year % 4:
    leap_year = True
```

Comment: check for all this year `1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2500, 2600 `

Comment: there are some exceptions

Comment: @Hackaholic read the code carefully. `not year % 4` evaluates true in all cases you mention.

Comment: @mattexx but they are not leap year, it should be false